# как синхронизировать ползунки на двух qgraphicsview?

Tags: c++, qt

у меня есть два qgraphicsview как синхронизировать их ползунки? то есть, если тянуть за один, то и менялся другой?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень просто, принять сигнал от одной и отправить сигнал к другой.

Comment: @megorit не могли бы Вы подробнее объяснить, пожалуйста

Comment: Подробнее читай дркументацию. А если не знаешь, что такое сигнально-слотовая система Qt, то читай книгу за авторством Шлее, хотя в документации про нее тоже достаточно подробно написано. В сети вообще сложно найти документацию лучше, чем у Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

два варианта.
напрямую связать сигналы одного со слотами второго:

```
connect(ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar(),SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),ui->graphicsView2->horizontalScrollBar(),SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar(),SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),ui->graphicsView2->verticalScrollBar(),SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

или через свой слот (если понадобится доп. обработка)

```
connect(ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar(),SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),this,SLOT(slotSliderMoved(int))); 
connect(ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar(),SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),this,SLOT(slotSliderMoved(int)));
....
void MainWindow::slotSliderMoved(int p)
{
    ui->graphicsView2->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->value());
    ui->graphicsView2->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()->value());

}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! мне подходит первый вариант!